# Do duplicate questions earn badges?

Tags: support, badges, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Are the questions, marked as duplicates still eligible to earn the badges? For example a 'Notable question' badge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are still eligible.

Views are still counted, you can still star them, and you can still vote on them.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952/best-programming-based-games) recently earned the poster a Stellar Question gold badge, despite being closed for nearly 2 years. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135126/onclick-vs-addeventlistener) was closed as a duplicate over a year ago, but recently qualified for a Famous Question gold badge.

The only thing that would prevent a question from being eligible for score, favourite and view related badges is deletion, although a locked post can no longer be voted on and thus won't be able to gain the votes needed for score-related badges.